What is a Reggie in slang? Origins and Characteristics
I read a blog and the blog told me that "Reggie" is a slang term often used to refer to low-quality or mid-grade marijuana. It's derived from the term "regular," indicating that it's not of particularly high quality or potency compared to other strains.
Are there more details about reggie's history and development? Could you please share the information with me?

It's in Green's Dictionary, but without any note about its etymology other than "Black."

According to UD the full name is: Reggie Miller  -  very low grade Marijuana. Also called Reggie for short.Also Reggie Milla Originated in Atlanta then spread out all through the south.

According to the site (genius.com) the full name for this low quality weed is Reggie Miller which refers to the famous basketball player as explained below.

this particular strand of weed is called “Reggie Miller” because it causes fits of coughing/choking after inhalation, a reference to Reggie Miller infamously giving Spike Lee the “choke sign” after scoring 8 points in 8.9 seconds against the New York Knicks (Spike’s favorite NBA team) in Game 1 of the 1995 NBA Eastern Conference Finals on May 7, 1995. Reggie’s quick-fire scoring helped his team, the Indiana Pacers, overcome a 105-99 point deficit to win Game 1 by just 2 points, 107-105.


(Facebook)
